# Starting a word with Caret and ending with Dollar does not produce expected result

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following code.

```
string pattern5 = "^ba$";
string myString5 = "badabyba";
bool match5 = Regex.IsMatch(myString5, pattern5);
Console.WriteLine(match5); // should print True but I see False
```

I want to find a match in a string which starts with `ba` and ends with `ba`. If I use both `^` and `$` in a single pattern it does not give me expected result. But if I use either `^` or `$` (`^ba` or `ba$`) then I get expected result, but if `myString5` is `ba` then it shows True, which is not what I want.

Is it illegal to use `^` and `$` together in this way?

Comment: Why did you choose to use a regex for that? [`myString5.StartsWith("ba") && myString5.EndsWith("ba")`](http://ideone.com/l6zpEo) is enough.

Answer (score 2):

`^` matches the start of the string and `$` matches the end. So the regular expression `^ba$` breaks down like this:

1. `^`: start of string
2. `b`: literal character 'b'
3. `a`: literal character 'a'
4. `$`: end of string

Your regular expression will therefore *only* match the precise string `ba`.

---

If I understand you correctly, what you actually want to do is match *any* string which both starts and ends with `ba`. So we need to use a wildcard.

```
^ba.*ba$
```

`.` matches "any character", and `*` modifies the previous expression to match 0-or-more times. So this regular expression matches like this:

1. `^`: start of string
2. `ba`: literal string "ba"
3. `.*`: **Any character, 0-or-more times**. That is, any sequence of any characters
4. `ba`: literal string "ba"
5. `$`: end of string

So `^ba.*ba$` will match any of these strings:

```
baba
bababa
bafoobarba
ba     ba
```

But not any of these:

```
ba
abba
bafoobar
```

I recommend experimenting with an [interactive regex tester](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: They *might* be looking for `^ba(.*ba)*$` if `ba` is meant to be a valid input

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - OP seems to be implying that they don't want to match `ba`: "if myString5 is "ba" then it shows True"

Answer (score 1):

> I want to find match in a string which starts with ba and end with ba

i think your pattern should look like

```
^ba.*ba$
```

`^` start of the string

`ba` the characters ba

`.*` any character 0 to n times

`$` the end of the string

Comment: could you explain a bit? It can be then "^ba*.*ba$" also. but I thought ba should be enough if since ^ba$ satisfy it

Comment: @RotatingWheel `^ba$` only matches `ba`, you need a wildcard like `.` that matches any character - because you want to allow any character between `ba` and `ba`

Answer (score 0):

The `^ba$` matches a whole string that equals `ba` since it only matches `b` at the beginning of the string, and `a` at the end of the string due to anchors `^` and `$` (this explanation is true since you are not using any regex options).

You need to just check if the string starts and ends with a substring. Then, you can use `String.StartsWith` and `String.EndsWith` methods.

```
string myString5 = "badabyba";
Console.WriteLine(myString5.StartsWith("ba") && myString5.EndsWith("ba"));
// => true
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/l6zpEo)

If you really need a regex for the check, you just need

```
Regex.IsMatch(myString5, @"^ba") && 
Regex.IsMatch(myString5, @"ba$", RegexOptions.RightToLeft)
```

See another [regex demo](http://ideone.com/buehNq)

Checking ending substring with `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` option makes it quicker and safer with very long input texts than with `(?s)^ba.*ba$` (with the inline singleline option), but you can use it, too. (Note that singleline mode is necessary for a dot to match newline symbols).